# Weird behavior of jQuery UI Explode in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, explode

I'm trying to show an background-image after a user clicks on a box. (I know I'm a bit lazy on the CSS)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {};
        $(".toggler1").click(function() {
            $("#effect1").effect("explode",options,1000);
            $(".toggler1").html("<div id='effect1b' style='float:left;width:207px;height:153px;></div>");
            return false;
        });
});
</script>
```

The image container is

```
<div class="toggler1">
    <div id="effect1" style="float:left;width:207px;height:153px;border:none;">
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The stylesheet is simply

```
<style type="text/css">
    #effect1b {
    background: url("2_01.jpg");
    }   
</style>
```

Why would this work in Firefox but not in IE? I think I'm going slightly insane!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your HTML is malformed. It is missing a closing quote.

```
$(".toggler1").html('<div id="effect1b" style="float:left;width:207px;height:153px;"></div>');
```